# Automated way to update all records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I have been making a database based on the 2013 college football season. I want to be able to update ALL team records by just running one SQL script.

```
SET @thisTeam='Oregon';
UPDATE team
SET wins=(
        SELECT COUNT(winner) FROM game WHERE winner=@thisTeam),
    losses=(
        SELECT COUNT(loser) FROM game WHERE loser=@thisTeam)
WHERE teamName=@thisTeam;
```

So far I have been manually updating my @thisTeam variable to update games. I tried to use a trigger, but as I understand it, I can't use a trigger in my 'game' table to execute an update in the 'team' table. This code works just fine, I just want a more automated way to do it. I'm new to SQL, and I would normally run a FOR EACH loop, but I've heard it's a really bad idea to do that with SQL.

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update a second table from a trigger. You can also update the table in one go:

```
with x as (
    select
        t.teamName,
        sum(case winner when t.teamname then 1 else 0 end) wins,
        sum(case loser when t.teamname then 1 else 0 end) losses
    from
        team t
            cross join
        game g
    group by
        t.teamName 
)
Update
    t
Set
    wins = x.wins,
    losses = x.losses
From
    team t
        inner join 
    x
        on t.teamName = x.teamName
```

Edit - simplified slightly

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30e75/3)</kbd>**

Comment: Wow. That worked like a charm! There was just an extra comma after the "sum...losses," part.

Thank you so much!